# Using regex in FTP for filenames for downloading files

Tags: regex, ftp, download

Is it possible to use regex for matching file names in FTP to get files from server ?

I need to do FTP to server and need to download the files whose file names are ending with the same value. In my case,  it is 14_04_25_144238.

I am not sure if it is doable. But, just out of curiosity, asking this.

Can we use regex like `.*14_04_25_144238` in the ftp get command ?

Thanks in advance.
Dinesh S

Comment: Maybe. Why don't you try it and see how it goes?

Comment: It won't work just by 'trying it' with the get command so I'm not sure why people are piling on the OP. You need a different command - see my answer.

Comment: @Paul then the question would be, why can't I use regex in that command? He just made the wrong question.

Comment: I think that's being over picky. The requirement was clear from the title/first line. So I answered that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the mget command.

From [the Unix man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ftp)

> mget remote-files
>
> Expand the remote-files on the remote machine and
>   do a get       for each file name thus produced.  See glob for details on
>          the filename expansion.  Resulting file names will then be 
>   processed according to case, ntrans, and nmap settings.        Files are
>   transferred into the local working directory, which        can be changed
>   with 'lcd directory'; new local directories        can be created with '!
>   mkdir directory'.

If you want to turn of the prompting of each file, then you also need this:

> prompt
>
> Toggle interactive prompting.  Interactive prompting occurs
>          during multiple file transfers to allow the user to selectively retrieve or store files.  If prompting is turned off (default is on), any mget or mput will transfer all files,         and any
>   mdelete will delete all files

.

Comment: One query Paul. I need to give 'y' for each files in the mget ? Is there any way to avoid it ?